# Cloning Angular2 Code from Plunker to your Machine

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wrote some applications with Angular but i'm new to Angular 2

In [Angular 2 official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) you have to create a quick start sample in order to run Angular

So , wanted to work with routing on Angular 2 with [another](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng2/helloworld#live-demo) tutorial but there is a difference, as you can see in the link it refers you to a plunker which works online but when i download it don't know how to run in

I tried to copy routing code to the quick start sample but it doesn't work and it stops

**So how can i run codes like [This](http://%20%20[3]:%20http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) (routing sample) on my machine?**

Thanks

Comment: Your links are not clear. You can copy paste the code from plunker

Comment: what do you mean not clear? it not a single page code to paste, here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

@Mojtaba vels4j is correct. Under the files part of that plnkr (top left) you can see all the files locally associated with the application. I think you mean you want the files referred to in the index.html in which case you can just copy the url link and paste it into the URL bar of a new tab or window.

Then copy all (Cmd + A) of it and save it to the project folder. Next you'd then need to update the index.html to refer to those files or load them in with System.js or Webpack or whatever you plan on using.